# convert 0:00 to 0:00.00 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that converts ms to s and m and it will display as 0:00 but i want it to display it as 0:00.0. How would i do this?

```js
function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
  var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
  return (seconds == 60 ? (minutes+1) + ":00" : minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds);
}

console.log(
  millisToMinutesAndSeconds(123456)
)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even try to add those additional numbers: you clearly know how to do the arithmetic necessary to add them, so why haven't you? Turn your milliseconds into minutes and seconds, then calculate how many milliseconds that leaves and add it to the end?

Comment: this wasnt my code i found it in an answer on this site

Comment: Then put that in your post, because right now you're strongly suggesting that this is your own code, and thus that you know how to program things involving basic arithemetic.

Comment: okey thanks i already found the answer but in case i will ask another question in the future i will do that

Comment: No, still put it in your post because even if you found an answer, others will find this post in the future when they're looking for answers to similar problems. If you got the answer _as answer to your post_, accept that answer, and if you found it somewhere else, you should delete this post again because if you were able to find the answer minutes after asking, then so can everyone else, and this post has no reason to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set toFixed() with the desired number of digits:

```js
var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I do not know where you got the code from, the code may look something like this. I suggest you close this question.

```js
function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
  const seconds = Math.floor((millis - (minutes * 60000))/ 1000);
  const milliseconds = (millis - (minutes * 60000) - (seconds * 1000));

  const mins = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : "" + minutes;
  const secs = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : "" + seconds;
  const msecs = milliseconds < 10 ? "00" + milliseconds : milliseconds < 100 ? "0" + milliseconds : "" + milliseconds;
  return `${mins}:${secs}.${msecs}`;
}

console.log(
  millisToMinutesAndSeconds(123456)
)
```